# Момент создания таблицы виртуальных функций с C++

Tags: c++

Как я понимаю для каждого класса, в котором есть хотя бы одна виртуальная функция, создается своя таблица виртуальных функций, т.е. для базового класса - одна таблица, а для производного - другая, содержимое которой может быть изменено, если какая-либо виртуальная функция переопределяется, или дополнено - если определяются новые виртуальные функции.

Любой объект, класс которого имеет виртуальные методы, неявно содержит указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций класса этого объекта. При создании объекта сначала вызывается конструктор его базового класса, в котором этот указатель инициализируется адресом таблицы базового класса, а затем, при вывозе конструктора производного класса, перезаписывается адресом таблицы производного класса.

*В какой момент создается таблица виртуальных функций*: в начале работы программы или при первом создании объекта, использующего эту таблицу? Зависит ли это от компилятора или прописано в стандарте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На примере MS Visual Studio и GCC: таблица виртуальных функций создаётся на этапе компиляции программы. В run-time нагрузки нет. Сам указатель на таблицу приписывается в объект в момент вызова конструктора (по факту в нем же, просто скрытой "нулевой" строкой).

Таблица обязана создаваться в момент компиляции хотя бы по той причине, что адреса функций нужно связать с их номерами в таблице для корректной замены всех вызовов на чтение адреса из таблицы и косвенный вызов по нему.

Comment: Адреса в момент компиляции неизвестны же.

Comment: Известны индентификаторы, которые в последствии превратятся в адреса. Я имел ввиду, что в готовом исполняемой файле таблица уже заполнена.

Comment: А можно подробнее узнать про этот процесс. Какой нибудь источник

Comment: Увы, источника нет, пишу по собственному опыту изучения программ, декомпилированных с помощью IDA Pro

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошо объяснили ваш вопрос: https://habrahabr.ru/post/51229/

> В C++ все функции по умолчанию имеют раннее связывание, то есть компилятор и компоновщик решают, какая именно функция должна быть вызвана, до запуска программы. Виртуальные функции имеют позднее связывание, то есть при вызове функции нужное тело выбирается на этапе выполнения программы.
>
> Встретив ключевое слово virtual, компилятор помечает, что для этого метода должно использоваться позднее связывание: для начала он создает для класса таблицу виртуальных функций, а в класс добавляет новый скрытый для программиста член — указатель на эту таблицу.

Answer (score -1):

В Стандарте про имплементации механизма виртуальных функций ничего не сказано, это зависит разработчиков компилятора.

Смею предположить, что таблицы создаются тогда, когда становится доступен тип, т.е. при загрузке исполняемого модуля.